# NKIssueContentStatus change to NKIssueContentStatusNone

Tags: ios, macos, newsstand-kit

In my app I have a “Delete” button which should delete the downloaded file and in background I want to change status to NKIssueContentStatusNone from NKIssueContentStatusAvailable.

I know the property is read only. I would like to ask what function to call to change the status from NKIssueContentStatusAvailable to NKIssueContentStatusNone.

Thanks!

Comment: `-[NKLibrary removeIssue:]`

Answer (score 0):

As jonahb said, use the `NKLibrary` method:

```
[NKLibrary removeIssue:issue]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do... I "reset" the issue like this:

```
-(NKIssue*) resetIssue:(NKIssue*)issue {
    NSString* issueName = [issue name];
    NSDate* issueDate = [issue date];
    NKLibrary * lib = [NKLibrary sharedLibrary];
    [lib removeIssue:issue];
    return [lib addIssueWithName:issueName date:issueDate];
}
```